# Find the value of each term in the objective function

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I want to calculate each one of the three terms in the objective function alone gurobi python. how can I do that?

The first term : `c*(te[i]+to[i]+t[i,s])*X[i,b,s] for i in Trucks for b in Blocks for s in Slots`
The second term: `d[b,s]*X[i,b,s] for i in Trucks for b in Blocks for s in Slots`
The third: `g*a[s]*X[i,b,s] for i in Trucks for b in Blocks for s in Slots`

The objective function equation

```
m.setObjective(quicksum(c*(te[i]+to[i]+t[i,s])*X[i,b,s] for i in Trucks for b in Blocks for s in Slots) + quicksum(d[b,s]*X[i,b,s] for i in Trucks for b in Blocks for s in Slots) +quicksum( g*a[s]*X[i,b,s] for i in Trucks for b in Blocks for s in Slots), GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to split up your objective into three separate [LinExpr](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_linexpr.html) objects. After optimizing, you can use the [getValue()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_linexpr_getvalue.html) method of these objects to extract the expression's value at the optimal solution.

In your case, one example of this is as follows:

```
# Construct three linear expressions
expr = []
expr.append(quicksum(c*(te[i]+to[i]+t[i,s])*X[i,b,s] for i in Trucks for b in Blocks for s in Slots))
expr.append(quicksum(d[b,s]*X[i,b,s] for i in Trucks for b in Blocks for s in Slots))
expr.append(quicksum(g*a[s]*X[i,b,s] for i in Trucks for b in Blocks for s in Slots))

# Set objective and optimize
m.setObjective(quicksum(expr[i] for i in range(3)), GRB.MINIMIZE)
m.optimize()

# Return linear expression values
if m.status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
    for i in range(3):
        print(expr[i].getValue())
else:
    print('Model not solved to optimality')
```